# Subfields of a Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $S=\{s+t\sqrt2+(u+v\sqrt2)i\mid s,t,u,v\in\mathbb Q\}$.
>   Find all subfields of $S$.

Clearly S is a subfield of S.
Past that I'm not really sure where to start.
The textbook doesn't give many notes and my professor doesn't lecture.

Comment: $S=(\mathbb Q{\sqrt2})[i]=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,i)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Note that $S={\bf Q}[\sqrt 2,i]$. It follows that the Galois group of $S$ over ${\bf Q}$ is isomorphic to $({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z})^2$ (check it!), so it's fairly easy to find all its subgroups. Apply the Galois theorem to find all subfields of $S$.